# Install npm bower offiline

Tags: bower

Is there any way to install `Bower` Offilne?

I'm trying to install `bower` but the same is probably being blocked by some proxy, I would need to install offline

I am using the command:

```
npm install -g bower on cmd and git cmd.
```

`node.js` and `npm` is instaled.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Bower zip file and install it as described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: Yes, thats the official site.